# Hiberbate query for the product search based it's category id

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a schema which consist of the following table. 
1)TABLE `category_type`. Basically we have 4 category_type 
a)Groceries
b)Pharma
c)Baby Products
d) Sports item

```
CREATE TABLE `category_type` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `object_version_number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

2) TABLE `category`. Table's description as follows. 
The `category_type` table and `category` table are different. Category Type table is the higher level as explain earlier. The `category` table consist of the next level of categorization. Ex) `Staples`,`Personal Care`,`Biscuit` and `Beverages` is the 2nd level of category which come under the main category_type `Groceries`.
All the next level of the categorization is been done in the same `category` table itself. Suppose `rice and pulses`,`flour`,`spices`,`salt and sugar` are the 3rd level of categorization with comes under staples category.So,all the 3rd level of the categorization refer to the 2nd level of categories using the "parent_category_id" field in the same table.Similarly 4th level of the categorization refer to the 3rd level  using the "parent_category_id" field in the same table.
Ex:
1). 1st level of categorization are Groceries,Pharma,Baby Products,Sport item
2). 2nd level of categorization are`rice and pulses`,`flour`,`spices`,`salt and sugar` using groceries. Similarly pharma,baby products,sport item will have there own 2nd level of categorization. 
3). Similarly each 2nd level of categories will have there own 3rd level of categories.
The table info is given below.

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `object_version_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_category_categorytype_id` (`category_type_id`),
  KEY `FK_parent_category_id` (`parent_category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_category_categorytype_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_type_id`) REFERENCES `category_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_parent_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1011 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

3)TABLE `product`.Now ultimately the product table come.It has `category_id` field which references to the `id` field in table `category`

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `manufacturer` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unique_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `image` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_updated_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `object_version_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNQ_product_unique_name` (`manufacturer`,`name`,`category_id`),
  KEY `FK_product_category_id` (`category_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_product_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1834 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The problem which i am facing is that i am not a write the hibernate query related to it is which i have to fetch all the data under `Staples` or `Personal Care` or `Biscuit` which is the 2nd level of categories whereas the product is been referred by the 4th level of category.

Please help me out.

The sample data of the `categoryType` table is as follows

```
    Id    name             images
    1   GROCERY /images/customer/groceries-icon.jpg 
    2   PHARMA  /images/customer/pharma-icon.jpg    
    3   GIFTS   /images/customer/gifts-icon.jpg 
    4   TOYS    /images/customer/toys-icon.jpg
```

The sample data of the `category` table is as follows

```
Id  Name         Category_type_id    parent_Category_id
53  Staples           1                     Null
54  Dry fruits        1                      53
55  Salt and Sugar    1                      53
56  Pasta,Noodles     1                      77
57  Pickles.Sauce     1                      77
58  BUSCITS           2                      Null
59  Ready to eats     1                      77
60  Oil and Ghee      1                      53
61  Flour And Suji    1                      53
62  Rices and Pulses  1                      53
63  TOILETERS         2                      Null
64  KIMIS NOODLES     2                      Null
65  KWALITY           2                      Null
66  HouseHold         1                      Null
67  Wash and Clean    1                      Null
68  Biscuit           1                      Null
69  Skin Care         1                       74
74  Personal Care     1                      Null
75  Babies Cares      1                       74
77  Packed Food       1                       56
78  Men               1                       74
79  Oral Care         1                       74
80  Hair Care         1                       74
81  Wellness          1                       74
82  Tea and Coffees   1                       90
83  Fruit Juice       1                       68
84  Health Drinks     1                       68
85  Laundries         1                       67
86  Utensils          1                       67
87  Cars              1                       67
88  Floors and Glass  1                       67
89  Kitchen           1                       67
90  Bathroom          1                       67
91  Shoes             1                       67
92  Skin care         1                       74
93  Baby Care         1                       74
94  Beauty            1                       74
95  Oral Care         1                       74
96  Hair Care         1                       74
97  Men               1                       74
98  Wellness          1                       74
99  Confectionary     1                       68
104 Stationary        1                       66
109 ABC               4                       75
110 Plain Rice        1                       62
111 Basmati Rice      1                       62
112 Idli & Dosa Rice  1                       62
113 Other Pulses      1                       62
114 Soya Chunks       1                       62
115 Beans             1                       62
116 Millites          1                       62
117 Atta              1                       61
118 Suji And Rava     1                       61
119 Besan And Maida   1                       61
120 Rice Flour        1                       61
121 Ragi Flour        1                       61
122 Other Flour       1                       61
123 Sunflower         1                       60
124 Blended Oil       1                       60
125 Other Oils        1                       60
126 Olive             1                       60
127 Ghee              1                       60
128 Dates             1                       54
129 Cashsew           1                       54
130 Figs And Rasin    1                       54
131 Almonds           1                       54
132 Other Dry Fruits  1                       54
133 Salt              1                       55
134 Sugar             1                       55
135 Jaggery           1                       55
136 Sugar Free        1                       55
137 Masala            1                       1010
138 Ground Spices     1                       1010
139 Wholes Sales      1                       1010
140 Inter Spices      1                       1010
141 Vermilli          1                       56
142 Noodles           1                       56
143 Pasta             1                       56
144 Papad             1                       56
145 Namkeen           1                       56
146 Snacks            1                       56
147 Chips             1                       56
148 Pasta             1                       56
149 Honey             1                       57
150 Jam               1                       57
151 Ketchup           1                       57
152 Choco & Peanut    1                       57
153 Sauce             1                       57
154 Pickles           1                       57
155 Vinegar           1                       57
156 Soup Mix          1                       59
157 Spreads           1                       57
158 Breakfast Mix     1                       59
159 Sweet MIx         1                       59
160 Snacks Mix        1                       59
161 Canned Food       1                       59
162 Frozen Vegetables 1                       59
163 Frozen Snacks     1                       59
164 Gravy Mix         1                       59
165 Soaps             1                       69
```

The sample data of the `product` table is as follows

```
prod_id  category_id    name                    Bar Code
1336        54      3-Roses             8901725123123   
1337        54      3-Roses-mind-sharp      WFN201  
1338        54      3-Roses-Natural-Care        WFN208  
1339        54      3-Roses-Top-Star            WFN410  
1340        54      Active-Wheel-Blue-Bar       WFN403  
1341        54      Active-Wheel-Gold       WFN406  
1342        54      Active-Wheel-Lemon-Orange   WFN408  
1343        54      Active-Wheel-with-Lemon-    WFN472  
1344        54      Annapurna-Crystal-Salt  WFN409  
1345        54      Annapurna-Farm-Fresh-Atta   WFN404  
1346        54      Annapurna-Powder-Salt       WFN405  
1347        54      Annapurna-Special-Atta  WFN407  
1348        54      AntiGerm-Vim            WFN051  
1349        55      AvianceXP               8901725121716   
1351        54      Axe-Apollo              WFN401  
1352        54      Axe-Blast               WFN100  
1353        54      Axe-Click               WFN125  
1354        54      Axe-Dark-Temptation     WFN124  
1355        56      Axe-Dark-Temptation     8901242114307   
1356        56      Axe-Dimension           901242114406    
1357        54      BANANA FLOWER           WFN075  
1358        54      BANANA LEAF         WFN077  
1359        54      BANANA NENDRAN          WFN003  
1360        54      BANANA PLANT            WFN607  
1361        54      BANANA RAW              WFN071  
1362        54      BANANA RED              WFN004  
1363        54      BANANA ROBUSTA          WFN001  
1364        54      BANANA YELLAKI          WFN002  
1365        57      BASIL SOJI 500 GM       8901869197240   
1366        54      BASLAE LEAF - 200 G     WFN202  
1367        54      BATANI SPROUT           T00034  
1368        54      BEANS AWAREYKAAYI       WFN012  
1370        54      BEANS COWPEA (Karamani) WFN010  
1371        54      BEANS DOUBLE            WFN013  
1372        54      BEANS FRENCH FLAT       WFN014  
1373        54      BEANS FRENCH HARICOT-       NATTI   WFN006  
1374        54      BEANS FRENCH ROUND      WFN005
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please can you post some sample data in the category table. Will help to understand the table structure

Comment: @ArunM: I had added the sample data.

Comment: Please can you check this link, http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/. This will help you write the query for the same